# How to install PostGIS correctly with OpenGeo Suite 4.0 community edition on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, boundless-suite

I have installed the OpenGeo Suite community edition, version 3 and 4, onto Ubuntu Server 10.04 and 12.04 multiple times in the past, with virtually no problems.  With the latest version of OpenGeo Suite (which includes PostGIS 2.1), I am able to install almost all of the components successfully, except PostGIS, on ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04.  With earlier editions, PostGIS was installed as part of the full Opengeo installation process, but now, although PostGreSQL 9.3 is successfully installed, there are no PostGIS or opengeo database templates installed, nor are the spatial functions installed. According to apt-get, however, PostGIS 2.1 is installed.

I have also attempted to install OpenGeo v4 community edition on a local ubuntu server on a vm.  Same issue... geoserver, geowebcache, the opengeo dashboard, PostGres 9.3, and PostGIS 2.1 all installed, but no opengeo or postgis databases, and no functions.  I'm wondering if this is an issue with the Opengeo installation package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGeo Suite 4 no longer creates a default database or user account. You can create these using the following steps:

Run `sudo su postgres -c psql` to connect to the database. At the psql prompt enter `CREATE ROLE opengeo PASSWORD 'opengeo' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;` to create the opengeo user with the password opengeo. Now quit psql with `\q`.

Next, open `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` in a text editor and change the line `local   all             all                                     peer` to `local   all             all                                     md5`. You will need to restart Postgres qith `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Once postgres has restarted run `createdb -U opengeo -W -E UTF8 opengeo` to create the opengeo database with the opengeo user. You should be prompted for your password. Now you can connect to the data base with `psql -U  opengeo -W` (again you will be prompted for a password). You can install PostGIS by running `create extension postgis;`.

After this is done you should be able to add a PostGIS store in GeoServer using the opengeo user.